# Riscv32-unknown-elf Linker Error after reading linker script : undefined reference to '_end'

Tags: c, gcc, configuration, linker, riscv

I'm trying to compile and link a custom made c code to risc v project but I'm getting these error in the making:

I'm new to this field so please excuse any mistakes.

```
/local/home/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/9.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: 
/local/home/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/9.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/crt0.o:
 in function `_start':
(.text+0x0): undefined reference to `__global_pointer$'
/local/home/s2500108/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/9.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: (.text+0x8): undefined reference to `_edata'
/local/home/s2500108/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/9.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: (.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_end'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also wanted to ask this:

After executing `./configure --prefix=/local/home/s2500108/riscv --with-abi=ilp32 --with-arch=rv32i`
  + `make`
and trying to compile a multiplication instruction in **c code** examle a=21, b=10; a * b the compiler does not output any error and produces elf files normally. Why is this happening? I want to make sure that **no multiplication** will take place.

Comment: Your question is not clear in a sense that what exactly you are trying to accomplish but the error is quite common. _start function is using __global_pointer$ variable to load the  global pointer register. You need to create __global_pointer$ in your linker file.
Here are some pointers you can read to understand what is global pointer and how it is used.
https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/arch/riscv/programmer/
https://www.sifive.com/blog/all-aboard-part-3-linker-relaxation-in-riscv-toolchain

Comment: @R.k.Lohana Thank you very much for your answer. I will check it out